# Calling HttpPost with a single string parameter not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, httpclient

I have the following .Net Core 2.2 controller method, which is always receiving a null value:

```
public class ValuesController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AddValue(string value)
    {
        var newValue = await DoSomethingWithValue(value); // value is null here
        // Other code
        return Ok();           
    }
}
```

The calling code is as follows:

```
string newValue = Guid.NewGuid();
//var stringContent = new StringContent(newValue);
var result = await httpClient.PostAsync(uri + newValue, null);
if (!result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
```

The controller method is called successfully, but whether I try to pass the value as HttpContent, or as a query parameter (e.g. myuri/AddValue/123) it still comes through as null. What could I be doing wrong here?

Comment: Try explicitly setting in coming from the body: `AddValue([FromBody] string value)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, that's not a query param; that's a route segment. If you want to receive it that way, you need to specify a route param:

```
[HttpPost("AddValue/{value}")]
```

Otherwise, you need to send it as an actual query param, i.e. `myuri/AddValue?value=123`.

As for the post, the default binding is `FromForm`, which is expecting an `x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data` encoded body, which is not what you're sending. You would need to do:

```
var stringContent = new StringContent($"value={newValue}", Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

Or you can actually use `FormUrlEncodedContent`:

```
var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    ["value"] = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
};
var formUrlEncodedContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
```